# kotlin error at * - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin

while building a simple currency converter app in android kotlin I got the following error at * operator ? what could be reason for the error.

[image: Kotlin Code]

Comment: What is the type of `rate` and `fromAmount` ?

Comment: @Amirhosein rate is of type Any? and fromAmount is Float?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use round() function with nullable Any and Float variables. Also you need to convert Any to Float.
Try to convert them with this example:

```
var rate : Any? = 5
var fromAmount : Float? = 3.5f

val result = round(rate!!.toString().toFloat() * fromAmount!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `rate` variable is nullable (`float?` I suppose), while multiplying operation work with non null values only.

Also [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) wasn't used here, so `rate` variable seems to be changeable. So I recommend to make it unchangeable (`val` variable), or use buffer variable like following:

```
val bufferRate = rate
if(bufferRate == null) {
    ...
} else {
    val convertedCurrency = fromAmount * bufferRate //here `bufferRate` should be smart casted to non nullable type
}
```